# Need Firefox CSS hack for different background

Tags: css, image, firefox, background

I have a Joomla site using a gif background with:

```
<body style="background-color:#eeeeee; background-image:url(/images/new-background.gif); background-position: top center; background-repeat:no-repeat;" >
```

In every browser, except Firefox, the current background is properly aligned with the page content.

Is there a CSS hack for Firefox that would force a different background image? Where would I put the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to force a different background, you should normalize the styles cross browser:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Additionally, you should keep your CSS in `.css` files linked via:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path/to/stylesheet.css" />
```

Comment: Thanks, issue resolved. Now I just have to rework the menu CSS, et al, to compensate for loss of padding. Strange though that only Firefox was affected.

Comment: @user1701147, you could add back the padding, or margin, whichever you'd prefer to have. Using `0` is just useful for making everything on the page relative to the top left corner.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your background.  It's your elements, it appears that you have some padding/margins being applied where you probably don't want them.  position.css applies:

```
* { margin: 0
    padding:3px 0;
  }
```

Comment: I had a feeling this was the issue, but I still don't understand why only Firefox would be misaligned.

Comment: I just quickly reviewed it, didn't dig deep into it.